# User Permission to Sync with Contacts

Tags: ios, permissions, synchronization, contacts

I have an IOS app

The Requirement: Sync Phone Contacts with App Contacts

Condition: When Reinstalling an updated version of the app onto the phone,

User is NOT prompted by IOS SYSTEM for permission to sync with Phone contacts.

USER had previously granted permission to the test flight version, so it seems our updated version does not prompt the user for permission to Access Camera and Sync Contacts because a flag has already been set establishing permission for the app to automatically sync in the background?

QUESTION:
Do we need to require the user to delete the previous Test Flight app from the phone in order to allow IOS to request user permission to sync contacts?

Al Comments welcome

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

- If the user **remove** the app, he **WILL** be prompted again for access to contacts.
- If the user **update** the app, he **WILL NOT** be prompted again for access to contacts.